# Bootstrap 3 scrollspy strange behaviour - not updating active class on scroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am implementing scrollspy (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) on the following website

http://www.bestcastlesintown.co.uk/RC/php/index.php

I have done so using data attributes on my `<body>` tag like so `<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".bcit-sidebar">`

Even though the HTML in my DOM is structured properly strangely enough scrollspy is not working and I cannot understand why. I have called it properly with data attributes - but the active class (coloured a light blue in the sidebar) is always applied to the `<li>` containing the `<a href="#party-games">Party Games</a>`. The sidebar is not updating the active class dynamically on the `<li>` when the user scrolls.

The data attributes should be applied to the body tag like this.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".YOUR NAV CONTAINER">
```

Also, I've made sure the sidebar navigation structure is like this with resolvable targets:

```
<div id="YOUR NAV CONTAINER">
     <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#SECTIONID">list item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#SECTIONID">list item2</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found the problem, after many tries...

Try to simply add a DOCTYPE :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    ...
```

Bootstrap requires an HTML5 DOCTYPE, you can see it in the [Basic Template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) paragraph :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It was also [mentioned in v2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html) that HTML5 DOCTYPE is required. It started to be obvious for v3.0.2.

Comment: I had a DOCTYPE - Just the wrong one. answering the question myself below.

Comment: `<html>` is not a DOCTYPE, your **must** add an HTML5 DOCTYPE (`<!DOCTYPE html>`). Bootstrap requires it.

Answer (score 0):

My DOCTYPE was wrong - for some reason this would stop the page from working:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I changed the DOCTYPE to:

```
<html lang="en">
```

and scrollspy works. If anyone can expand on the reasons why please do so.